# Select data.table columns based on condition, within by

Tags: r, data.table

I want to extract data.table columns if their contents fulfill a criteria. And I need a method that will work with by (or in some other way within combinations of columns). I am not very experienced with data.table and have tried my best with .SDcol and what else I could think of.

Example: I often have datasets with observations at multiple time points for multiple subjects. They also contain covariates which do not vary within subjects.

```
dt1 <- data.table(
    id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
    time=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
    meas=c(452,23,555,33,322,32),
    age=c(30,30,54,54,20,20),
    bw=c(75,75,81,81,69,70)
)
```

How do I (efficiently) select the columns that do not vary within id (in this case, id and age)? I'd like a function call that would return

```
    id age
1:  1  30
2:  2  54
3:  3  20
```

And how do I select the columns that do vary within ID (so drop age)? The function call should return:

```
   id time meas bw
1:  1    1  452 75
2:  1    2   23 75
3:  2    1  555 81
4:  2    2   33 81
5:  3    1  322 69
6:  3    2   32 70
```

Of course, I am interested if you know of a function that addresses the specific example above, but I am even more curious on how to do this generally. Columns that contain more than two values > 1000 within any combinations of id and time in by=.(id,time), or whatever...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I (efficiently) select the columns that do not vary within id (in this case, id and age)?

Maybe something like:

```
f <- function(DT, byChar) {
    cols <- Reduce(intersect, DT[, .(.(names(.SD)[sapply(.SD, uniqueN)==1])), byChar]$V1)
    unique(DT[, c(byChar, cols), with=FALSE])
}
f(dt1, "id")
```

output:

```
   id age
1:  1  30
2:  2  54
3:  3  20
```

---

> And how do I select the columns that do vary within ID (so drop age)?

Similarly,

```
f2 <- function(DT, byChar, k) {
    cols <- Reduce(intersect, DT[, .(.(names(.SD)[sapply(.SD, uniqueN)>k])), byChar]$V1)
    unique(DT[, c(byChar, cols), with=FALSE])
}
f2(dt1, "id", 1)
```

output:

```
   id time meas
1:  1    1  452
2:  1    2   23
3:  2    1  555
4:  2    2   33
5:  3    1  322
6:  3    2   32
```

---

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(
    id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
    time=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
    meas=c(452,23,555,33,322,32),
    age=c(30,30,54,54,20,20),
    bw=c(75,75,81,81,69,70)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, chinsoon12. I really like your solution, but unfortunately my example wasn't good enough. I now added a wt column which varies for only one subject (which means it should be dropped when we look for the columns that do not vary within "id"). Your suggestion then fails and returns the error: "j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group". I hope you can help with adjusting your otherwise brilliant suggestion.

Comment: what is your expected output for the new dataset?

Comment: I added the expected output. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Please see my own reply. I would like to give the credit to chinsoon12, because you showed me the principle. But I also want other users to be guided to the complete answer. @chinsoon12, could you update your answer either by copying my code or providing your own way to get to the same?

Answer (score 0):

This might also be an option:

Count unique values per column, by ID (using `data.table::uniqueN` )
Check in which columns the sum of unique values (by group) equals the number of unique IDs (using `colSums`)
Only keep (or drop) the wanted columns

```
library(data.table)
ids <- uniqueN(dt1$id)
#no variation
dt1[, c( TRUE, colSums( dt1[, lapply( .SD, uniqueN ), by = id ][,-1]) == ids ), with = FALSE]

   id age
1:  1  30
2:  1  30
3:  2  54
4:  2  54
5:  3  20
6:  3  20

#variation
dt1[, c( TRUE, !colSums( dt1[, lapply( .SD, uniqueN ), by = id ][,-1]) == ids ), with = FALSE]

   id time meas bw
1:  1    1  452 75
2:  1    2   23 75
3:  2    1  555 81
4:  2    2   33 81
5:  3    1  322 69
6:  3    2   32 70
```

Comment: Thanks Wimpel. Your suggestion is not general though. The way id is handled is specific to this example. The solution should be general enough for the by variable(s) to be multiple columns and to be anywhere in data (your suggestion assumes that it is the first column).

Answer (score 0):

Based on chinsoon12's suggestion, I managed to put something together. I need four steps, and I'm not sure how efficient it is, but at least it does the job. To recap, this is the dataset:

```
dt1
   id time meas age bw
1:  1    1  452  30 75
2:  1    2   23  30 75
3:  2    1  555  54 81
4:  2    2   33  54 81
5:  3    1  322  20 69
6:  3    2   32  20 70
```

I put this together to get the columns that are constant within "id" (only age):

```
cols.id <- "id"
dt2 <- dt1[, .SD[, lapply(.SD, function(x)uniqueN(x)==1)], by=cols.id]
ifkeep <- dt2[,sapply(.SD,all),.SDcols=!(cols.id)]
keep <- c(cols.id,setdiff(colnames(dt2),cols.id)[ifkeep])
unique(dt1[,keep,with=F])
   id age
1:  1  30
2:  2  54
3:  3  20
```

And to get the columns that vary within any value of "id" (age is dropped):

```
cols.id <- "id"
## differenct from above: ==1 -> >1
dt2 <- dt1[, .SD[, lapply(.SD, function(x)uniqueN(x)>1)], by=cols.id]
## difference from above: all -> any
ifkeep <- dt2[,sapply(.SD,any),.SDcols=!(cols.id)]
keep <- c(cols.id,setdiff(colnames(dt2),cols.id)[ifkeep])
unique(dt1[,keep,with=F])

   id time meas bw
1:  1    1  452 75
2:  1    2   23 75
3:  2    1  555 81
4:  2    2   33 81
5:  3    1  322 69
6:  3    2   32 70
```